# jQuery timed link animation - in time with slide show

Tags: jquery, animation, hyperlink, slideshow, timed

My problem is this: I have a jQuery slideshow which fades in/out a list of images. I need to, if possible have a set of links alongside this slide show which grow or zoom slightly in time with the fading in of the images they describe.

I.e. There are 4 images in the loop and 4 links to the left that relate to the images, I would like the link that corresponds to the current image to be highlighted in some way(grow, zoom, etc)

I've found plenty of documentation around animating text 'onmouseover/onmousehover' but what I would ideally like to do is have the animations in sync with the related images. I realise that this would be much easier in Flash but, for SEO and usability reasons I require the links to be real text or at the very least sprite images with text indents( cufon would also be fine if this offers a solution to this problem)

Below is a link to a very basic design of the banner(be kind), the slide show works but the links are currently just a static image. Hopefully with the description and this example you'll be able to fully understand the effect I am trying to achieve.

[Link to example](http://www.d-syne.com/rotator)

Many thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I am aware that you can use jQuery to 'inject' values in to CSS so I assume that the font-size property of the links could be increased and decreased and this action could be animated with jQuery. I'm just not sure how to apply this set of behavoiurs. I am a jQuery novice.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to achieve with the text? You want to increase the size of the link when you move over it?

Comment: I want the links to increase in size/then out again as the photo that corresponds to it fades in. i.e. The interval of the image swap is 5000ms so when the chimney lining image shows i want the chimney lining link to basically grow and return to the original size thus indicating to the user what the current image relates to. Here is a flash version of the banner.[flash example](http://d-syne.com/rotator/home.swf) Wait until the links have come in from the left, the second cycle shows the zoom in/out effect i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to modify the link's style. Example:

```
$( "#link1" ).animate({
   color:red, opacity: .5
}, 1000, "linear", function(){ alert("all done"); });
```

Comment: @tiagoboldt Thanks for the comment so if i wanted to animate a zoom effect it would go something like this: '$( "#link1" ).animate({ font-size:120%}, 2000);' so to make it reduce straight after would i just do the opposite directly after i.e. '$( "#link1" ).animate({ font-size:100%}, 2000);' and repeat this process for each link, increasing the interval time? One more question, will this potentially be out of sync with the rotating images due to the load times of each separate element(links and image rotator)? thanks

Comment: The usage is right:) On the sync part, well, maybe you should call animate() only when you also call the rotation of the images (or whenever you want it to happen). Don't trust on time intervals as they cannot be reliable (events might start in slightly different times). --- Do mark the answer as valid if it helped so that it can help those with the same question. Good luck

Comment: @tiagoboldt This is helpful and i understand the explanation the .animate method should be part of the rotator function to prevent sync issues, however as a complete jQuery noob, i would really appreciate it if you could check [this code](http://d-syne.com/rotator/topcon.js)  from the banner in my example and explain briefly how to place the .animate methods. Theres no specific rule for each image and therefore it's unclear how i would tie this method to each rotate event, I'm almost there and will certainly mark the answer if you can help just a little bit more! thanks again

Comment: after a bit of tinkering and guess work. i got it to work, check the code out at the same link i provided before for a basic demo of the concept working, the links below animate in time with the fading of the images! you're a star